# Dot product of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $x=(x_1, x_2,\cdots)$ be an absolutely convergent sequence and $y=(y_1, y_2, \cdots)$ be any sequence where $y_i\in\mathbb{C}$. If $y=(y_1, y_2, y_3, \cdots)$ is not bounded then the dot product of two sequences does not converge?

I thought about the example case. If $y=(1, 2, 3, \cdots)$ and $x=(1, 1/2, 1/3, \cdots)$, then their dot product is not converging. But this is only one example of the statement. I want to know how this statement always holds.

Comment: What about $y = (1,2,3,\dots)$ and $x = (1, \frac{1}{2^3}, \frac{1}{3^3}, \dots)$. Then the series of their dot-product becomes $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ which converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have pointed out that the result stated is false, but nobody's given the obvious correct version:

> > If $(y_j)$ is not bounded then there exists $(x_j)$ with $|sum|x_j|<\infty$ and $\sum x_jy_j$ divergent. (In fact we can obtain $x_j y_j>0$, $\sum x_jy_j=+\infty$.)

**Hint:** First show there is a strictly increasing sequence $(j_k)$ with $|y_{j_k}|>2^k$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain why the correct version holds? I don't see how that works. I am sorry...

Comment: @7954321561 I added a big hint

Answer (score 4):

Extreme counterexample: $x=0,0,0,\cdots$ is absolutely convergent.

---

Less extreme: take any absolutely convergent series $z_k$ and set $$x_k:=\dfrac{z_k}{y_k}$$ (except where $y_k=0$).

Comment: Extreme, but absolutely... convincing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove this because it is false. $\sum \frac  1 {n^{3}}$ is absolutely convergent and $(1,2,3,...)$ is not bounded but $\sum n\frac  1 {n^{3}}$    is convergent.